# What's the right way to pass some initial data to a new window?

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I'm just learning Electron, and I'm trying to open a file and display it in a new window.  I click a button in the initial (root) window, which then opens an "open file" dialog, from which I can get a file path.  I would like to then open that file, create a window, and pass the contents of the file to the new window.  My issue is in getting the string with the file contents into the callback function for when the window is ready; i that even possible?  My main.js code:

```js
function createWindow (templateFile, initialData) 
{  console.log("Creating window....")
   newWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800,
                                  height: 600,
                                  webPreferences: {preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
                                                   nodeIntegration: true}
                                 })
    newWindow.loadFile(templateFile)
    newWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
//This is what doesn't work; I want to take the initialData argument to the createWindow function, 
//and get it into the 'did-finish-load' callback function
    newWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', (event, initialData) => 
    {   windowsArray[newWindow.webContents.id] = newWindow 
        console.log(initialData)
        newWindow.webContents.send("initialDataLoad", initialData)
    })
    newWindow.on('closed', function () {newWindow.object = null})
}

ipcMain.on("new-sheet", (event, gameDefinitionFile) => 
{    console.log("Loading " + gameDefinitionFile)
     let gameDefContents
     fs.readFile(gameDefinitionFile, 'ascii', (err, gameDefContents) => {})
     createWindow("defaultSheet.html", gameDefContents)
})
```

I have read that you can just make a new attribute on the webContents object and then refer to it from the renderer process, but that does not sound like the actual right thing to do.  So, what should I do instead?

full code at https://gitlab.com/sjbrown8/osiris

Comment: Your `windowsArray` isn't defined and the statement using it will throw an exception. Also, what sends the `"new-sheet"` event? It seems to me you omitted some code. I think it's best if you included everything, stripped to bare minimum that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @amn yeah I did; windowsArray is a global variable, and the new-sheet event is sent by the button click in the root window. I can add more code, but yeah I was trying to only post the relevant portions. I should clarify that the program runs fine, it's just that in the renderer process I just get undefined where I'm expecting the file contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `webContents` way should solve your problem in an easy way. It's straightforward: you create and collect all data the window needs in advance, then you spawn the window with that.

There a a few constraints with the `webContents` way, because the `webContents` object that you create on `main` is serialized and send to `render`- meaning, both processes have independent versions of the object:

1. Changes you apply to you object on the render process version of your data will not be reflected into main (and vice-versa)
2. You can't pass functions (like using that to call a function from main on the render process)

But with plain initialization data: it's easy and understandable.

Edit:

Sure, the send methods needs a channel name and an optional objekt, that is the data that you want to send. You can write a function like so:

```
sendPersonData(personData) => {
   webContents.send('person-data-updated', personData);
);
```

Or if you want a function that takes a callback for flexible sending:

```
updatePersonData(personData, senderCallback) => {
   updatedPersonData = functionToUpdatePersonData(personData);
   senderCallback(personData);
}

// and use that like so:
updatePersonData({name: 'John Doe'}, sendPersonData);
```

Comment: I just don't want to get used to it, because ultimately what I'm doing shouldn't be THAT hard, and I can see wanting to do it in other, less forgiving circumstances in the future.  I will confess I'm also new to event-based programming though, so I could just be gun-shy, and I could be trying to do something that you're just not supposed to do, which is (I'll try to phrase this right) set an argument to a callback function when it's attached, not when it's called.

Comment: It's not about getting used to something but taking the tool from the toolbox that fits the best. I don't think, there is a "best" solution that fits all requirements. If you see your initial data as part of the webcontents for the browser window: then attach it to it. If it makes more sense, for how you app works, that the window first starts uninitialized and requests it's initialization data: ipc events is the preferred solution.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do that.  But in thinking about the issue, I realized I had a more fundamental question that's at the heart of the matter.  Let's say I am attaching a callback function to some event, and I want to set what is sent into that function at attachment time, not at call time.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Listening on the renderer has one big disadvantage. The renderer get's the data only once and if you allow a refresh of the browser window (CTRL+R), then the browser window will loose the data and will not get initialised again.

To my opinion, its safer to have the renderer pull in the initial data like so:

#### Renderer

```js
let initialData;
ipcRenderer.invoke('fetch-initial-data')
  .then((data) => initialData = data);
```

#### Main

```js
const initialData = createItSomehow();
ipcMain.handle('fetch-initial-data', () => initialData);
```

This way, the data will always fetched from the 'backend' when we refresh the screen. Note that it's async on the renderer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you need to do but you can use the [ready-to-show](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-show) event to send data to a new window before the window is shown for the first time.

This probably makes the most sense if the data is being used to populate existing page elements – though I guess there is no reason you can't blow out whatever was on the page with the new data – it's just another render.

> While loading the page, the ready-to-show event will be emitted when
>   the renderer process has rendered the page for the first time if the
>   window has not been shown yet.

**Main.js**

```
mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(basicMenu);

    let data = "some data that have have read from disk and want to send to this new window"
    mainWindow.webContents.send('message', { "event": "data dump", data: data});
    mainWindow.show()
})
```

---

**Renderer**

```
ipcRenderer.on('message', (event, arg) => {
  switch (arg.event) {
      case "data dump":

       // just a <textArea> but you could do anything with the data.
      $("#dump").text(arg.data);
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: That's kinda what I was trying to do, though I used newWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', ...  The problem I'm having is I want to pass in the data from outside the callback function.  So where you're defining data with the "let data = '...'" line, I set it elsewhere.  Trying to get it in where it's supposed to go is what I don't know how to do.